# wp caldera form plugin bootstrap datepicker disable days

Tags: wordpress, twitter-bootstrap, datepicker, days

i have read much about the bootstrap datepicker (which is also used by caldera form wordpress plugin) on stackoverflow.

i want to disable all mondays and tuesdays with an if condition.

if number < 8 on another input field then (on click on the date field) load datepicker without mondays and tuesdays.

on caldera forms you can easily choose a date input field with datepicker by drag and drop.

**i think the problem is that the plugin is instantiating the datepicker automaticly and you have no previous options**

am i right that the **solution could be** to take a normal text input field and instantiating the datepicker by my own script?

or is there any solution to get it easily work with the caldera plugin?

thanks :-)